# gnu screen: previous search result

Tags: gnu-screen

In GNU Screen, I can do a reverse text search by pressing ^A and then typing `[?search_string`, and press `n` to go to the next (reverse search) result. But if I go too far and want to go back one result, pressing `N` or `p` simply says "Copy mode aborted" and takes me back to the bottom of the screen. How can I go back to the last result without starting over from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point in the past few years I found an answer.

Instead of using `?`, you can use ^R and start typing a string for an incremental reverse search. Hitting ^R will continue the search (going up in the scrollback) and ^S will go back down to the previous match.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a single keystroke to reverse the search direction as supported by `vim` or `less`, but you can do this in three keystrokes:

1. <kbd>/</kbd>  (start forward search)
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd> (previous entry in search history)
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. <kbd>n</kbd> ...

To reverse direction again, press <kbd>?</kbd> for step 1.